# Create array of elements with same class

Tags: arrays, html-lists, each

Would this be an acceptable method of creating an array of

elements having the same class, or is there something more efficient?

```
<ul>
  <li  class="show" id="all">All Posts</li>
  <li  class="show" id="user" data-user="7">My Posts</li>
  <li  class="show" id="follow">Following</li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function() {
  var newarr=[];
  $("li").click(function(event) {
    var name = event.target.className;
    var newclass = 'choice';

  $(this).addClass(newclass);
  $(this).siblings().removeClass(newclass);

  $('li[class~=' + newclass + ']').each(function(index) {
    var thisid = $(this).attr('id');
    newarr[index] = thisid;
    })

  $.each(newarr,function(index,value) {
    //console.log(index + value);
        })

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `map` function to create the array:

```
var newarr = $('li[class~=' + newclass + ']').map(function(){ 
                 return $(this).attr('id');
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

im guessing `newarr[index] = thisid;` should just be `newarr[] = thisid;`.

but then again i dont even think i understand what you want to do.

why are you working from the .click handler?

on each click you set newclass to the clicked item and add it to the array. but you also remove the newclass from the siblings, so the previously clicked items will lose the newclass again... so in newarr only the last clicked item will have newclass

Comment: I omitted the code which shows that I have several <ul>'s from which a user can make a selection so there could be multiple values in the array. Does that affect your question to me as to why I am working from the click handler?